# Show equality (fourier series)

Tags: proof-verification, fourier-series

I'm working with fourier series and came upon a proof of Dirichlet's and Fejér's kernels. Within these proofs, there is an equality that I just can't wrap my head around, some help would be greatly appreciated.

$$2\pi D_n(u) = \sum_{n=-N}^Ne^{inu} = e^{-iNu}\sum_{n=0}^{2N}e^{inu} = e^{-inu}\frac{1-e^{i(2N+1)u}}{1-e^{iu}}$$

Comment: A particular one of those equalities? Or the entire string?

Comment: Equality 1 is trivial (I think?), but equality 2 and 3 are a problem for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
   \sum_{n=-N}^{N}e^{inu}& = e^{-iNu}+e^{-i(N-1)u}+\cdots+1+\cdots+e^{i(N-1)u}+e^{iNu} \\
   & = e^{-iNu}\left\{1+e^{iu}+e^{2iu}+\cdots+e^{2iNu}\right\} \\
   & = e^{-iNu}\left\{(e^{iu})^{0}+(e^{iu})^{1}+(e^{iu})^{2}+\cdots+(e^{iu})^{2N}\right\}
\end{align}
The final series a truncated geometric series of the form
$$
          S=1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{2N}
$$
The trick is to multiply by $(1-x)$ in order to get a telescoping sum
\begin{align}
    (1-x)S  = &1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{2N} \\
           & - (x+x^2+x^3+\cdots x^{2N}+x^{2N+1}) \\
            = & 1-x^{2N+1} \\
       S = &\frac{1-x^{2N+1}}{1-x}
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$   \sum_{n=-N}^{N}e^{inu} =  e^{-iNu}\frac{1-e^{i(2N+1)u}}{1-e^{iu}}.$$